# How to organize serializers using fastjsonapi.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, fastjsonapi

My application has following versions: `rails 6.0.0`, `ruby 2.6.3`.

I have around 20 controllers in the application and we have planned to use `fast-json-api` instead of `rabl` as serializer in the app. I found the number of serializer files growing very fast for each controller. (screenshot below).

---

#### Questions

**Is there a better way to organise all the serializers?**

I have tried the following 2 ways to organise:

1. Organizing all serializers of one controller under its model-name (like rabl)

   [image: serializer]

   But it gave me this error:
   `NameError (uninitialized constant Api::V1::LexiconsController::ListNodeSerializer)`
2. Can I render different api view in single Serializer, by keeping all the SerializerClassNames in the same serialzer file for that controller??

   **Serializer for Category Controller**

```rb
    class ShowSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
      cache_options enabled: true, cache_length: 24.hours

      attributes :name, :status, :description
    end

    class IndexSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
      attributes :name, :status, :thumbnail, :definition

      attributes :area do |area|
        area.country.try(:name).try(:html_safe)
      end
    end
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: How are you calling the Serializer in your controller? You must have to use double-colon to call your serializers ```::Lexicons::ListNodeSerializer``` ```::Lexicons::LexiconSerializer```